# I am trying to compare strings, but it is not recognizing

Tags: java, string, if-statement

So I am trying to check strings using an if statement,I created like a test computer which gives predetermined responses depending on the input, the only inputs which are working happen to be hi or hello, strings with spaces do not seem to work, why is that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ComputaBot {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text;
    String computer = "ComputaBot:";
    String[] input = {
            "how are you?", "hi", "hello", "what is your name",
            "do you like chicken?", "where are you from?",
            "do you like cheese?"
    };

    do{
        System.out.println("Type to talk!:");
        text = scan.next();

    if (text.equals(input[1]) || text.equals(input[2])) {
        System.out.println(computer + " " +"Hello!");

    }else if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(input[0])) {
        System.out.println(computer + " " +"I'm fine, you?!");
    }else if (text.equals(input[3])) {
        System.out.println(computer + " " +"Jimmy");
    }else if (text.equals(input[4])) {
        System.out.println(computer + " " +"Yes! Love it");
    }else if (text.equals(input[5])){
        System.out.println(computer + " " +"Germany");
    }else if (text.equals(input[6])){
        System.out.println(computer + " " +"only on pizza");
    }else 
        System.out.println("bye");
    }while(!text.equals("bye"));

    scan.close();
}
 }
```

Comment: because `scan.next()` only gets one word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `next()` reads one word. What you should use is `nextLine()` which reads a whole line (delimited by a new-line character entered when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
text = scan.nextLine();
```

From [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29):

> **public String next()**: Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

Comment: Don't forget about dropping the answer to lowercase, too.

Comment: @alvonellos that's handled by `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Comment: Oh! My eyes totally skipped over that line (probably because I was looking for something else) Good answer, though. You're like a ninja, this is the second post I've seen you answer in less than a minute -- there should be a badge for something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
scan.nextLine()
```

instead of

```
scan.next()
```

Answer (score 0):

Scan.next() only read in the next word, you want scan.nextLine() for the complete line.  It would be better if you use Map add all questions/answers as pair so that you don't have to do all that if/then/else statements.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComputaBot {

   public ComputaBot() {
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      String text;
      String computer = "ComputaBot:";
      Map<String,String> bot = new HashMap<String,String>();
      bot.put("how are you?", "I'm fine, you?!");
      bot.put("how are you?", "Hello!");
      bot.put("hi", "Hello!");
      bot.put("what is your name", "Jimmy");
      bot.put("do you like chicken?", "Yes! Love it");
      bot.put("where are you from?", "Germany");
      bot.put("do you like cheese?", "only on pizza");

      do {
         System.out.println("Type to talk!:");
         text = scan.nextLine();

         String answer = bot.get(text.toLowerCase());
         System.out.println(computer + " " + answer);
      } while (!text.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"));
      scan.close();
   }
}
```